# How to create a simple watchdog using Systemd?

Tags: bash, systemd

I have a simple script that checks if certain long running processes (ie forever) are running and if not, restarts them (some detail omitted):

```
#!/bin/bash

PROC_LIST=$(ps ax | grep <stuff>)

while read cfg
do
  PROC_NAME=$(echo $cam_cfg | cut -f2 -d' ')
  PROC_COUNT=$(echo $PROC_LIST | tr ' ' '\n' | grep $PROC_NAME | wc -l)
  if [[ $PROC_COUNT -eq 0 ]]; then
    echo "Starting process for $PROC_NAME"
    <process start> 2> /dev/null &
  fi
done < $CONFIG
```

The idea here is to get a list of relevant processes and see if they contain the keywords specified in the config file. I suspect the important bit is that I fork the process if needed with an &. This script works if I run it manually.

I want Systemd to run this script evert 30 seconds. For this, I created the following units:

service:

```
[Unit]
Description=Check processes

[Service]
Type=oneshot
WorkingDirectory=/home/user/scripts
ExecStart=/home/user/scripts/watchdog.sh /config
User=user

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

timer:

```
[Unit]
Description=Check running processes

[Timer]
OnBootSec=30s
OnActiveSec=30s

[Install]
WantedBy=timers.target
```

When using Type=oneshot, I find that the watched processes do not start at all, and so every 30 seconds the timer kicks in and tries to start all the processes again. I suspect this is because I am forking, and so when the service ends, all child processes end too.

When I used Type=forking, I see the processes start and remain as required. However in this case the timer is never scheduled so never runs again. I suspect this is because it doesn't realise the forking service needs reactivating. So:

1. How do I fix the above so that the script is run every 30 seconds regardless of anything?
2. This exercise makes me feel that I'm actually working against systemd. Is there a better design for this? CONFIG is an arbitrary and possibly dynamic list so I'm a little reluctant to create a systemd service for each entry.

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem. What are the "long running" processes, why do they stop? Why did you not consider a wrapper script?

Comment: The process is an ffmpeg instance that is writing keyframes from an IP camera to disk. Sometimes (eg due to network issues), the stream is lost and ffmpeg quits. I'd like to ensure that it starts up again soonish after (eg within 30 seconds). Regarding wrapper scripts... well that's what I thought I was doing :)

Comment: `pidof` will find the process ID of a running program., or return 1 if the program was not found running.